# PowerShell PSCredential Argument List

Tags: windows, powershell

I need to connect to a remote server and do some file copies and moves, etc. The remote server requires authentication.

What UNC path do I need to enter in for PSCredential? Is it the path to a particular remote user like

```
\SERVER2\Users\Administrator
```

Or is it the path to the remote resource itself like

```
\SERVER2\Data\Content
```

...

#### Authenticate the call

```
$Creds = New-Object -Typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -Argumentlist "C:\Some\Path",$PW
 Copy-Item  $src $destination -Credential $Creds
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the username. Your paths are not proper UNC paths however. They should start with two slashes like `\\SERVER2\Users\Administrator`

Answer (score 1):

Specify the credentials of the user with permission to access the resource.  The [Get-Credential](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849815.aspx) commandlet can get the credentials for you.

```
$cred = Get-Credential
Copy-Item $src $destination -Credential $cred
```